# XLIFF source-language setting when using message codes for the <source> attribute

Tags: localization, xliff

I am using "message codes" eg "person.name" in my Symfony framework project. I use corresponding xliff message code files. Since this is a message code used as an index what is the correct or normal approach to setting the "source-language" attribute. eg here:

```
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="person.name">
                <source>person.name</source>
                <target>Name</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per BCP47, you should be able to use `und` (Undetermined), but I strongly recommend not to use the approach that you are using (to populate `source` with string ID or what you mentioned as "message codes"). The reason for it is that Xliff is intended to be a two-language, parallel resource where it could be easily parsed to get the translation for each language either based on string ID or based on source or target language. The tools that translators use consume Xliffs in this manner and provide the translator the content on `source` tag as source language and they should populate the content of `target` based on that source string.

If you populate the `source` with string ID, that defeats the purpose. The common way of using Xliff with your example is:

```
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" target-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="person.name">
                <source>Name</source>
                <target>Vorname</target>
            </trans-unit>
            <trans-unit id="person.surname">
                <source>Surname</source>
                <target>Nachname</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Comment: Using an ID in <source> is a known issue with Symfony, see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20076#issuecomment-294126923

Comment: Right. Didn't know that. Seems like a misunderstanding on the side of maintainers about how a bilingual file format like Xliff works and how it has to be interchangeable with other tools. Obviously, I should be able to access: (a) target string by looking up the source string, (b) source string by looking up the target string, and (c) look up the pair of source and target using resname.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  (I filed that issue, someday maybe I will find time to open a PR.)